# Android: run always in background

Tags: android, service, mobile-development

i am developing a simple program that should create a notification with some data when the mobile battery is low.

the application is working fine, but I must open the app by myself at first or if the phone was switched off and on, and if the user closed the app from the currently running apps menu it will close too.

How can i make it like truecaller for example so that after the user opens it after the installation it will continue working forever ?

Answer (score 1):

You must start your monitoring service on Boot of the device for it to be available after a reboot of the device.

Example BroadcastReceiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This receiver `BootReceiver` can then start your `Service`.

Your App will be needed to be ran at least once by the user manually, after installation. This is a security procedure in Android.

Answer (score 0):

I think http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html would do you good.

> The IntentService class provides a straightforward structure for running an operation on a single background thread. This allows it to handle long-running operations without affecting your user interface's responsiveness. Also, an IntentService isn't affected by most user interface lifecycle events, so it continues to run in circumstances that would shut down an AsyncTask